# Azure Durable Function - Worker Failed to load function

Tags: python, azure, function, azure-durable-functions

I am trying to create a durable function using python in vscode for one of my work, here I have defined the function call in the orchestrator function, starter function and defined the corresponding activity functions.I have tried function chaining but I am getting the following error.

To add more clarity I have defined few activity functions DMBucket1, DMBucket2, DMBucket3, DMBucket4, DMRandomization,DMPullFromDB, DMPushTODB. Inaddition to this I also have a orchestrator function and starter function.

My orchestrator Function:

```
import logging
def orchestrator_function(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):
 df,df_curr,df_prev,df_roster,name_data1,manager_name,data1 = yield context.call_activity('DMPullFromDB', None)
 bucket1 = yield context.call_activity('DMBucket1', df,df_curr,df_prev,df_roster,name_data1,manager_name,data1)
 bucket2 = yield context.call_activity('DMBucket2', df,df_curr,df_prev,df_roster,name_data1,manager_name,data1)
 bucket3 = yield context.call_activity('DMBucket3', df,df_curr,df_prev,df_roster,name_data1,manager_name,data1)
 bucket4 = yield context.call_activity('DMBucket4', df,df_curr,df_prev,df_roster,name_data1,manager_name,data1)
 rand = yield context.call_activity('DMRandomization', bucket1,bucket2,bucket3,bucket4,data1,df_roster)
 pushDB = yield context.call_activity('DMPushToDB', rand)
 if pushDB==1:
    return("The DB push was successful")
 return("DB push was not successful")

main = df.Orchestrator.create(orchestrator_function)
```

My Activity Function PullFromDB is as below:

```
import logging
import pandas as pd

#To convert all the elements in a dataframe to lower case 
def preprocessing(df):
 df=df.applymap(lambda x: x.lower() if type(x) == str else x)
 return df

#Fixing the name data file i.e. removing the agents who does not have first and last name or has multiple names
def name_fix(df):
 df1=df.groupby(["employeeid"]).first().reset_index()
 return(df1)

def main():

 df_roster=pd.read_csv("df_roster.csv")
 df_curr=pd.read_csv("df_curr.csv")
 df_prev=pd.read_csv("df_prev.csv")
 df=pd.read_csv("df.csv")
 manager_name=pd.read_csv("manager_name.csv")
 name_data=pd.read_csv("name_data.csv")

 #preprocessing 
 df_roster=preprocessing(df_roster)
 df_curr=preprocessing(df_curr)
 df_prev=preprocessing(df_prev)
 df=preprocessing(df)
 manager_name=preprocessing(manager_name)
 name_data=preprocessing(name_data)
 logging.info('Preprocessing is complete')

 #name_data
 name_data1=name_fix(name_data)

 #Conversion for Roster
 df_roster['recorddate'] = pd.to_datetime(df_roster['recorddate'])
 df_roster['recmonth'] = df_roster['recorddate'].dt.month
 df_roster['recyear'] = df_roster['recorddate'].dt.year

 data=df.merge(df_roster,on = ['companyguid','organization','primaryprogram','employeeid','recyear','recmonth'],how="left")
 data1 = data[['companyguid','organization','primaryprogram','employeeid','recmonth','recyear','metricname','metrictype','goal','actualvalue','Manageremployeeid']]


 return(df,df_curr,df_prev,df_roster,name_data1,manager_name,data1)
```

When I try to run the function I am getting the following error:

```
Worker failed to load function: 'DMBucket1' with function id: 'cee913fa-8cf2-4f28-9665-ed47d801c18b'.

[2022-06-15T15:06:04.969Z] Result: Failure
Exception: FunctionLoadError: cannot load the DMBucket1 function: the following parameters are declared in Python but not in function.json: {'df_curr', 'df', 'manager_name', 'df_roster', 'name_data1', 'data1', 'df_prev'}        
 
 Stack:   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.8/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 321, in _handle__function_load_request
self._functions.add_function( 
 File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.8/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\functions.py", line 112, in add_function
```

Answer (score -1):

> [2022-06-15T15:06:04.969Z] Result: Failure
> Exception: FunctionLoadError: cannot load the DMBucket1 function: the following parameters are declared in Python but not in function.json: {'df_curr', 'df', 'manager_name', 'df_roster', 'name_data1', 'data1', 'df_prev'}

This exception clearly saying that you have not defined the variables in `function.json` to use in your python code of Azure Function App.

For example,

`init.py`:

```py
def main(req: func.HttpRequest, msg: func.Out[str]) -> func.HttpResponse:
    msg.set("This is test 01")
    return func.HttpResponse("This is a test function.")
```

You have to define the variable **`msg`** in the `function.json` like:

```
{
      "type": "queue",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "msg",
      "queueName": "outqueue",
      "connection": "AzureStorageConString"
    }
```